# Where in iOS/iPhone app is the best place to save data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to save data to a Plist and I figured the best place would be in the Delegate .m "applicationWillTerminate" since Apple thoughtfully places a comment there "Save data if appropriate".

However, it seems that this method never gets called when I'm testing with the iPhone Simulator. My NSLog statement never gets run.

So, is this the best place to save data when exiting the app and if so, do you know why it never seems to get called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since iOS 4 applications can enter in "background" instead of terminating, so `applicationWillTerminate:` may not be called.

You may want to use `applicationDidEnterBackground:` also. You can create a method to save the data and call it in both delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks - I just ran a test and it always seems to go to "applicationDidEnterBackground". So when does an app actually exit?

Comment: When the user closes it in the bottom bar (which appears by double-pressing the home button or swiping up with 4 fingers on an iPad properly configured). You can hold the icon pressed until the red "-" appears.

Comment: That's specific to certain generations though - my iPod 2G doesn't do that. I just ran my app on the device and it calls "applicationDidEnterBackground" and then "applicationWillTerminate" immediately after. So going to BG is probably best, or as Keller states below, whenever the data changes. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I remember iPods 2g can't fully run iOS 4, and had a special  version with limited features…

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just save your Plist when it is changed, that way you always know the data is up to date.